# GWT CellTable: How to Update A TextBox Dynamically

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

I have the following **CellTable**
[image: CellTable]

When the user clicks the **Pay Min.** CheckBox, it should copy the value from the **Due Now** column over to the **Pay Today** text field AND recalculate the total for the **Pay Today** column.

Here is the code for the **CheckboxCell** (**Pay Min.**) and the **TextInputCell** (**Pay Today**) columns:

```
private Column<AccountInvoice, Boolean> buildPayMin() {

    columnPayMin = new Column<AccountInvoice, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(AccountInvoice object) {
            return object.isPayMinimum();
        }

        @Override 
        public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, AccountInvoice object, NativeEvent event){

            // Get event type
            int eventType = Event.as(event).getTypeInt();

            // See if this is a 'change' event
            if (eventType == Event.ONCHANGE) {

                String value = columnMinDue.getValue(object);

                // Get the cell to copy the value from                  
                TextInputCell cell = (TextInputCell) columnPayToday.getCell();
                // Re-create the view data for the cell
                TextInputCell.ViewData viewData = new TextInputCell.ViewData(value);
                cell.setViewData(object, viewData);
                // Refresh
                cellTable.redraw();

                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    };
    columnPayMin.setDataStoreName(columnPayMinHeader);
    columnPayMin.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    columnPayMin.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    return columnPayMin;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------

private Column<AccountInvoice, String> buildPayToday() {
    columnPayToday = new Column<AccountInvoice, String>(new TextInputCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(AccountInvoice object) {
            return object.getPaymentAmount();
        }
    };
    columnPayToday.setDataStoreName(columnPayTodayHeader);
    columnPayToday.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<AccountInvoice, String>() {
        @Override
        public void update(int index, AccountInvoice object, String value) {
            object.setPaymentAmount(value);
            cellTable.redraw();
        }
    });
    return columnPayToday;
}
```

I can get the value to copy over, but the total for the **Pay Today** column doesn't refresh. It seems to refresh only when a value is manually entered into the **Pay Today** text field. I even tried doing:

```
columnPayToday.getFieldUpdater().update(context.getIndex(), object, value);
```

which didn't help either.

Thanks for any help you might provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewData` represents a temporary value in your TextInputCell. When you call `cellTable.redraw()`, the TextInputCell reverts to the original value (the one from `getValue()` method for that column).

Do not redraw the table if you want to modify only the "view" state of TextInputCell, or call `accountInvoice.setPayToday#` (or whatever method is there) to update the object and then call refresh() on your ListDataProvider (which is a more efficient way to update a table compared to redraw).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Please see how I modified the code according to your suggestions: http://pastebin.com/Z4bQYrzf 
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. The ***`Window.alert`*** triggers only ones, somehow ***`dataProviderList.refresh()`*** following it, kills it and it doesn't trigger even when the checkbox is checked again. I also decided to use ***FieldUpdater*** instead of ***onBrowserEvent***, which has no effect, but the code is shorter.

Comment: You still call `cellTable.redraw()` - this time in the FieldUpdater in the other column. Your poor table gets redrawn all the time! You should almost never call redraw() anywhere in your code.